# MapReduce job is failing with an error failed to write data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to export data from teradata to hadoop. but my export query is failing by giving an error "Failed to write data".Please look at the Mapreduce and application logs below:

```
Log Type: syslog
Log Upload Time: Tue Mar 08 22:59:27 -0800 2016
Log Length: 4931
2016-03-08 22:47:07,414 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-maptask.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
2016-03-08 22:47:07,499 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-03-08 22:47:07,499 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2016-03-08 22:47:07,509 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2016-03-08 22:47:07,510 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1457504560070_0004, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@175b9425)
2016-03-08 22:47:07,556 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: RM_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 39.7.48.2:8032,39.7.48.3:8032, Ident: (owner=hive, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=oozie, issueDate=1457506410968, maxDate=1458111210968, sequenceNumber=908, masterKeyId=280)
2016-03-08 22:47:07,599 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2016-03-08 22:47:07,848 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /data1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data2/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data4/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data5/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data6/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data7/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data8/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data9/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data10/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004,/data12/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hive/appcache/application_1457504560070_0004
2016-03-08 22:47:08,132 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2016-03-08 22:47:08,623 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2016-03-08 22:47:08,840 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: com.teradata.dynaload.hcatalog.mapper.TDInputFormat$TeradataInputSplit@2ece4966
2016-03-08 22:47:08,844 INFO [main] com.teradata.dynaload.hcatalog.mapper.TDInputFormat$TeradataRecordReader: recordreader class com.teradata.dynaload.hcatalog.mapper.TDInputFormat$TeradataRecordReaderinitialize time is:  1457506028844
2016-03-08 22:47:09,512 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 300417020(1201668080)
2016-03-08 22:47:09,512 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 1146
2016-03-08 22:47:09,512 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 841167680
2016-03-08 22:47:09,512 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 1201668096
2016-03-08 22:47:09,512 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 300417020; length = 75104256
2016-03-08 22:47:09,515 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2016-03-08 22:47:09,518 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
2016-03-08 22:47:09,518 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
2016-03-08 22:47:09,848 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.local does not exist
2016-03-08 22:47:09,914 INFO [main] hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://apus2.labs.teradata.com:9083
2016-03-08 22:47:09,951 INFO [main] hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
2016-03-08 22:47:10,407 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
2016-03-08 22:47:10,452 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2016-03-08 22:47:10,453 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.work.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.output.dir
2016-03-08 22:47:10,453 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
2016-03-08 22:47:10,457 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class

APPLICATION Master LOGS:

Log Type: stderr
Log Upload Time: Tue Mar 08 22:59:27 -0800 2016
Log Length: 240
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Log Type: stdout
Log Upload Time: Tue Mar 08 22:59:27 -0800 2016
Log Length: 0

Log Type: syslog
Log Upload Time: Tue Mar 08 22:59:27 -0800 2016
Log Length: 66959
Showing 4096 bytes of 66959 total. Click here for the full log.
ILED
2016-03-08 22:59:19,325 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: In stop, writing event JOB_FAILED
2016-03-08 22:59:19,456 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copying hdfs://C423A:8020/user/hive/.staging/job_1457504560070_0004/job_1457504560070_0004_1.jhist to hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004-1457506422934-hive-oozie%3Aaction%3AT%3Djava%3AW%3DTDExportMR%3AA%3Dexport%3AID%3D00001-1457506759193-0-0-FAILED-default-1457506429243.jhist_tmp
2016-03-08 22:59:19,550 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copied to done location: hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004-1457506422934-hive-oozie%3Aaction%3AT%3Djava%3AW%3DTDExportMR%3AA%3Dexport%3AID%3D00001-1457506759193-0-0-FAILED-default-1457506429243.jhist_tmp
2016-03-08 22:59:19,562 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copying hdfs://C423A:8020/user/hive/.staging/job_1457504560070_0004/job_1457504560070_0004_1_conf.xml to hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004_conf.xml_tmp
2016-03-08 22:59:19,614 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copied to done location: hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004_conf.xml_tmp
2016-03-08 22:59:19,645 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Moved tmp to done: hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004.summary_tmp to hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004.summary
2016-03-08 22:59:19,654 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Moved tmp to done: hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004_conf.xml_tmp to hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004_conf.xml
2016-03-08 22:59:19,666 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Moved tmp to done: hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004-1457506422934-hive-oozie%3Aaction%3AT%3Djava%3AW%3DTDExportMR%3AA%3Dexport%3AID%3D00001-1457506759193-0-0-FAILED-default-1457506429243.jhist_tmp to hdfs://C423A:8020/mr-history/tmp/hive/job_1457504560070_0004-1457506422934-hive-oozie%3Aaction%3AT%3Djava%3AW%3DTDExportMR%3AA%3Dexport%3AID%3D00001-1457506759193-0-0-FAILED-default-1457506429243.jhist
2016-03-08 22:59:19,666 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Stopped JobHistoryEventHandler. super.stop()
2016-03-08 22:59:19,671 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator: Setting job diagnostics to Task failed task_1457504560070_0004_m_000004
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

2016-03-08 22:59:19,672 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator: History url is http://apus2.labs.teradata.com:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1457504560070_0004
2016-03-08 22:59:19,680 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
2016-03-08 22:59:20,682 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Final Stats: PendingReds:1 ScheduledMaps:0 ScheduledReds:0 AssignedMaps:7 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:0 CompletedReds:0 ContAlloc:7 ContRel:0 HostLocal:6 RackLocal:1
2016-03-08 22:59:20,684 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://C423A /user/hive/.staging/job_1457504560070_0004
2016-03-08 22:59:20,711 INFO [Thread-89] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 46067
2016-03-08 22:59:20,712 INFO [IPC Server listener on 46067] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 46067
2016-03-08 22:59:20,712 INFO [IPC Server Responder] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2016-03-08 22:59:20,714 INFO [TaskHeartbeatHandler PingChecker] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.TaskHeartbeatHandler: TaskHeartbeatHandler thread interrupted.
```

Plese help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using sqoop to bring data to hadoop. Please paste command you are running. For "Failed to write data" , there can be multiple issues. destination parent directory is not avialble, space is not there at cluster etc.Only command can give explanation.

Comment: INSERT INTO tiestpg.WebSales_Export_large_RC@jrtest2 SELECT * FROM tiestpg.WebSales_large_RC_dgtest;

Comment: where jrtest2 is my foreign server name containing all needed parameters to connect my TD database with hadoop

Comment: We're using td-sqlh teradata internal connector to provide transfer of data from one source to another.